# Power Query - Save Variable To Specific Cell and Table

Tags: powerquery

This may be a basic question but I can only see answers around reading but can any one advise on the syntax to save a var created in PowerQuery to a table/cell so it can be saved and refrenced ?

Thanks

Terran

Comment: Thanks - this is what I am lookng for... how do I specify the location ? Plan is to capture some vairables I create for problem solving as the diagnotics is not giving me every thing I need.

Comment: When you specify load to a table in file...close and load... it prompts for location you want to put it on the spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks - I can not mark this closed but if you post it as the answer I'll mark it ;)

Comment: "Not looking to load a set of data just a few vars and use code that I can use." Sorry, I don't understand what that means, perhaps someone else can help you, I deleted my answer

Answer (score 1):

If your query is a single-cell table, a single-element list, or a single scalar (text, logical, date, datetime, etc, etc), then you load it to the workbook like any other query. It will appear as a single-element table.

Then, anywhere else in your workbook, select an empty cell, press `=` to start editing a cell formula, then click the value in that table the query made.

If your query is named QueryNameHere and is a single-cell table with its column's title as ColumnTitleHere, the formula in the cell you're editing will likely be something like `=QueryNameHere[ColumnTitleHere]` which means the array of values in that column but since it's a single row the cell formula is equivalent to "the value within the table".

If you're willing to add a layer of complexity you can have simpler formulas and greater flexibility in the future if your take that cell formula and create a new named value from it. For example: Maybe you'll later decide you have a bunch of single values like this and instead of one query per value you decide to consolidate all of them into a single query that is a two-column table of name/value pairs. You can then manage the names values and change the formula to be an `XLOOKUP` against your new table, and none of the dependent formulas in the rest of your workbook would need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

When using Power BI rather than sending to a cell expose using the following as an example.

Variable shown in the error then.

```
initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)) otherwise error headers,
```